# Prevent notice and warnings in error_reporting?

Tags: plugin-development, errors, wp-debug

When turning opn WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY, I get tons of warnings and notices. I have tried to remove the warnings by doing a @ini_set('error_reporting', 1) to only show E_ERROR, but I still get tons of E_NOTICE.

Is there someway to prevent all the warnings and notices and only show errors in HTML output?

Comment: Keep in mind that this is by design. If your site spits many notices / warningn with WP_DEBUG on, it's a sign that the Add-Ons you're using are not state-of-the-art. Plugin authors can make use of the WP_DEBUG setting to find about problematic areas in their application. It is used for programming and quality assurance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off WP_DEBUG because it overwrite your `ini_set`.

Comment: Thanks. @ini_set('display_errors',1);@ini_set('error_reporting',1); worked when I turned off WP_DEBUG.